# How do I animate a facial animation sprite sheet?

Tags: animation, texturing, uv, faces

I made a face animation sprite sheet like this, [image]

with multiple faces on one texture sprite sheet.
I've tried animate it by moving its UV, but it stays the same whenever I play the animation.
What should I do to animate them?

Comment: [Here is the node setup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lb0pW3_jWlo) it works as expected I've tested it the past week. Be sure to apply the sprite sheet to a plane with the correct dimension.