# How to animate swapping image textures? (I'n a sustainable way)

Tags: animation, texturing, materials

Ok so, I'm having a problem with changing image textures. Simply put, I need one object to have one texture one frame, and another the next. I know the obvious solution is to use "Clones" with the new texture... but... that has become unsustainable(for context I'm making a piece like Paper Mario where the characters are flat 2d objects) because of the amount of textures I'm creating! So... I require a simple way to  swap textures without using a "Clone"

Comment: Just thinking out loud... Is there some way to use image sequences here?

Comment: yep, image sequence and keyframe the offset

Comment: Something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l84oLfb0HgU ?

Comment: Putting a pair of textures in with MixRGB nodes might work, too: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58165/fac-input-in-blender

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186911/blender-2-8-how-to-use-image-sequence-as-a-texture **and** https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36793/92768 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39876/movie-clip-on-plane

Comment: There is also [sprite sheets](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48448/how-do-i-animate-a-facial-animation-sprite-sheet)  if that's something that would help

Comment: you can also move the texture with the help of an empty

Comment: Don;t know you'd consider it simple but [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186703/how-can-i-animate-multiple-objects-to-be-highlighted-in-a-scene/186719#186719) is also an answer with a way to swap out a material with another on a specified frame using python.

Comment: @moonboots what do you mean by that?